# when i try to naive-bayes-classifier form https://github.com/muatik/naive-bayes-classifier i getting like error

Tags: python, hadoop, machine-learning, data-science

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-93a644f2878c> in <module>()
      3 import operator
      4 from functools import reduce
----> 5 from ExceptionNotSeen import NotSeen
      6 from naiveBayesClassifier.trainedData import TrainedData
      7 from naiveBayesClassifier import tokenizer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ExceptionNotSeen'
```

how can I solve this issue?

Go to this folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/py>thon3.5/site-packages/naive Bayes classifier Copy ExceptionNotSeen.py to your current project path(where you run your main python program it also their but I getting error like that only

Answer (score 2):

Other people have been experiencing this issue, as listed on the project’s GitHub issues page. This solution worked for one such individual:

> seems there is something wrong with the install import or python path in system variable.
> Solve it this way
>
> Go to this folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/py>thon3.5/site-packages/naiveBayesClassifier
> Copy ExceptionNotSeen.py to your current project path(where you run your main python program
> It solved that issue for me.

If this fails you should verify the location of ExceptionNotSeen.py, as others have noted, this error seems to exclusively occur when running in a virtual environment.

Lastly I suggest you use a more developed library for a Naive Bayes Classification implementation. Take a look at the heavily used sklearn package.